# Пример из книги с применением оператора continue

Tags: java

у меня вопрос, что за слово outer и откуда оно взялось:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        outer:
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                if (j > i) {
                    System.out.println("");
                    continue outer;
                }
                System.out.print(" " + (i * j));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Коротко: `outer` - это метка (label). И `continue`/`break` умеют на нее переходить.

Зачем это нужно? дело в том, что в java как бы нет `goto`(на самом деле такое слово есть, но использовать его нельзя). Но `goto`, не смотря на то, что Дейкстра его заклеймил, иногда очень удобно. И в Java пошли на компромисс - расширили `break`/`continue`. Только логику чуточку поменяли - в большинстве языков `break`/`continue` переходят только на один уровень вложенности циклов, а в java - на сколько нужно.

Ссылка на [офф документацию](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html). Там оно называется labeled and unlabeled break/coninue.

Answer (score 2):

Перед циклом `for` у вас стоит метка `outer:` (3-я строка в вашем коде). Оператор

```
continue outer;
```

делает переход на эту метку, то есть возвращает в начало первого цикла.

Comment: Точнее было бы сказать в место инициализации главного цикла.

Answer (score 0):

`outer` (Внешний) - это название метки, которое может быть любым. Просто, тот кто писал эту метку хотел внести смысл в название, поэтому так и назвал. А смысл состоит в том, что эта метка означает место куда передается управление программы когда выполняется оператор `continue`.

В данном случае она тут ненужная, как и оператор `continue`, кототорые можно удалить. Вместо этого можно использовать `break` без метки.

```
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        if (j > i) {
          System.out.println("");
          break;
        }
        System.out.print(" " + (i * j));
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: как же бесконечный цикл, если тут 10 на 10 итераций. А смысл в том, что создается "лесенка" за счет перевода строки (первая строка 1 символ, вторая -2 и тд) и ничего удалять не нужно, все на своем месте и нужное

Comment: так не получится, где вы увидели "лесенка" не могу понять.

Comment: что если запустить программу и посмотреть, что получится

Comment: @pavlofff точно, получается "лесенка" :) поправил